# How should I answer this interview question?

Tags: api, rest

I found this interview question for a company I'm interested in joining soon.

> Consider that you have an API that is called from the UI to display some data using pagination. How would you change the API call if for a non UI client you need to retrieve all data at once without pagination (petabytes of data)?

How would you answer this?

Comment: _“How would you answer this?”_ - only by laughing at whoever is asking this, because with _petabytes_ of data, this question does not have any connection to reality IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

Firstly, **this is not a question for StackOverflow**.  This question is better suited for software engineering Stack Exchange. Secondly, my answer would be "I don't recommend sending petabytes of data from and HTTP request".  However I will attempt to give the answer.

## Chunked Transfer Encoding

The only acceptable answer to this question is to enable chunking.  Essentially chunking allows you to retrieve an unlimited amount of data through and HTTP call by dividing the stream into non-overlapping chunks.  The chunks are received independently of each other and the connection is managed appropriately.  To enable this in an http reuqest/response you can utilize the following header

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

There are a variety of optional trailing headers that can be supplied

```
chunked-body   = *chunk
                 last-chunk
                 trailer-part
                 CRLF

chunk          = chunk-size [ chunk-ext ] CRLF
                 chunk-data CRLF
chunk-size     = 1*HEXDIG
last-chunk     = 1*("0") [ chunk-ext ] CRLF

chunk-data     = 1*OCTET ; a sequence of chunk-size octets
```

Chunking became part of the standard in HTTP1.1 so this will be ineffective on HTTP1.0

However, if the issue is the size of the response you would need to implement chunking server side not as part of the client.  I feel as though this is a misunderstanding of chunking on the interviewers part ( because I can't imagine what else they would be referring to ).